# How to protect public REST API from attackers using network sniffing tools

Tags: rest, http, security, reverse-engineering, api-key

We are developing a desktop application in C++ which is distributed to our customers. It will communicate with the server using REST API over HTTPS. We are concerned about network sniffing software, such as Wireshark. By using such tools, malicious users could record the HTTPS traffic, extract request URL, headers and body and perform requests to our backend REST API server on their own using automated scripts or Postman.

I read an [article](https://approov.io/blog/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key) which suggests that API keys should be used to identify that requests are really sent from C++ application. However, I don't understand how API keys prevent users from sniffing traffic? If API keys are included in HTTP header, they are still easily extracted by Wireshark.

Are there any other ways for ensuring that requests to our REST API server are actually sent from genuine and unmodified C++ application that we developed? How can we ensure that even if attackers use Wireshark, they won't be able to call REST API on their own using Postman (outside of our C++ application)?

Answer (score 1):

Sending the API key inside a TLS encrypted session (HTTPS) is perfectly safe as the headers are encrypted as well. The only thing that you may find in cleartext is the hostname/SNI of the server.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is absolutely no way to make sure, that the requests are sent from the 'genuine and unmodified C++ application'. But if you want to raise the bar and make it way harder for an attacker to e.g. perform a Man in the Middle (MitM) attack and analyze the traffic, you can do following:

1. API keys are a good thing. Do it.
2. Pin the certificates to make MitM attack way harder to perform. Wireshark will see the traffic still, but it will be encrypted.
3. Obfuscate the code, so even a binary analysis becomes harder.

This will not hold back a motivated attacker, but it will raise the bar significantly and unless you are doing banking apps (which I believe you don't, as banks buy themselves security solutions out of the box from some companies specializing in security design), then it may be simply not worth it to go through all the trouble of attacking apps with such protection.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. I have a question regarding your 1st point. I had an idea that each request from C++ to REST API should be a 2-step process. 1st step would be to call `/GetToken` endpoint, which would issue a single-use access token. 2nd step would be to call the actual endpoint (ex. `/GetLicenseData`) with the token attached in the HTTP header. Once the token is used, it is no longer valid. Would this be a good approach to increase security?

Comment: Question regarding your 2nd point: We are already using HTTPS for our REST API. What would happen if I didn't pin the certificates? Would the traffic still be encrypted if user sniffed it with Wireshark?

Comment: Yes. But a simple proxy like Burp or OWASP Zap can be used to perform a MitM attack. It will just offer you a different certificate and if the application considers it valid, the proxy will be able to decrypt the whole traffic. Certificate pining is meant to prevent that.

Comment: Regarding the first question - the token is to be left hardcoded in the application as an application secret. Obfuscation is meant to protect the secret in the binary. TLS and certificate pining are meant to protect the secret in transit.

Comment: Ok, I understand the need for certificate pinning now. Regarding app secret being hardcoded in the C++ application binary: Imagine that the user somehow decompiles the application and extracts the API key. Since it is hardcoded in the source code, it is the same for ALL our customers. If we detect any abnormal requests with this API key, we can't revoke it because all other customers who have C++ app installed wouldn't be able to get data from the API anymore. If we choose 2-step process with single-use token, then we can revoke just the token from suspicious customer. Does it make sense?

Comment: The purpose of this kind of API token is NOT to blacklist. If you want to detect anomalies and blacklist something, blacklist the user based on his identity.

Comment: Our C++ application doesn't require any form of user login. When customers purchase a license, they enter the code in the application and the correct features are unlocked. Our application has no such thing as "user identity" and we have no plans to implement any kind of login/register functionality.

Comment: Maybe we can use customer's IP as user's identity. But, users can still use VPN to appear as different IP.

Comment: You need some kind of secret between the client and the server if you want to protect the API or limit the calls. Without user authentication you have nothing that would allow you to distinguish between a normal user and someone misusing your API.